# Change wordpress database post table under guid column only post id

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Is it possible if I can change WordPress database post table under column only post id ?

Now at this moment WordPress database table :

1. WP post table - a. WordPress post table where insert is example.com/post-id.

[image: original]

Please see post table column guid.

But I need to look like below.

[image]

I need only post id.

Comment: your question is not clear, can you please elaborate in detail ?

Comment: please see these images ....

Comment: i want to insert only post id in database wp-post table under guid column . not need to site url . but how ??

Comment: its quite meaningless to change such fields, I'm afraid none of the WP function allow to do so.